# Apply All Transform Change Rig Size

Tags: rigging

I made a silly mistake, which was weight painting before making my model into correct size.
So I go ahead and scale everything and hit apply all transform, but to find out the rig for some reason become bigger. I then also find out every time I apply transform to the rig it grow larger.

It is something designed by default, or is it something I should fix?

Some may say to leave the rig alone and don't apply scale on it, but when I import the model into Unity it seams like the bone scale is causing some problems.

[The File can be downloaded here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s5d5IM_o9UKLEYw0RdK1QG--oqaKZL2p/view?usp=sharing)